# Compile MeteorJS app to WindowsPhone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, meteor, phonegap-plugins

I would like to build my current project to 3 main mobile platforms: iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8.

At the moment I can compile it to iOS and Android, but can't find any info for compiling it to WindowsPhone. I've heard that there was no support for this platform but since MeteorJS is available on Windows platform maybe something has changed?

If it is not possible in the straight way, maybe someone tried to compile MeteorJS to Node.js and then to WindowsPhone app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor doesn't support Windows Phone (and probably never will).

Windows and Windows Phone are actually very different operating systems. Going forward 'Windows Phone' will be superseded by the Mobile version of Windows 10 which are very similar platforms. Maybe support will come then.

In the mean time it is possible to build straight PhoneGap/Cordova apps for Windows Phone.

Comment: Yeah I know it is possible, but it drives me crazy to configure all the things related with compiling app to proper target system. Meteor makes it really easy to me and I was searching for something similar.

Comment: "(and probably never will)" what is your source?

Comment: @Kyll I base my "and probably never will" on the fact that: it's been around for over two years and they haven't added support yet; it has a much smaller market share than the other platforms that Meteor supports; and it's about to be superseded by a new platform (Windows 10 mobile) that *most* devices running Windows Phone will, theoretically, be able to update to.